# How to fix DirectoryNotFoundException while using Process in Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Pdf2Text in an ASP.NET web app. The web interface allows PDF files to be uploaded and converted to text. To convert to text, I use the C# function below, which relies on running the Pdf2Text program via the `Process` library.

```
void ExtractOCR(string input, string output)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("ocr/Pdf2Text.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = input + " " + output;

    Process exeProcess;
    using (exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

I've double-checked that the input and output paths are all valid. However, when I run the web app, I get the following error.

[image: An unhandled exception ('System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException') occurred in Pdf2Text.exe]

I've tried the Just-In-Time debugger but it won't even run for some reason. The Pdf2Text is a precompiled file, I don't have it's source code. I believe **[this](http://www.pdf2text.com/)** is the file's download site, but not 100% sure. I've checked online to find solutions to similar errors but none has worked.

Comment: It is clear in the error message, that the specified directory is their in the given path

Comment: Maybe, pool's user doesn't have access into the directories.

Comment: Thanks! That actually fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @GraDea for suggesting to look into the pool's permissions into the web app directory, this was the solution.

The web app was located at a custom location (not the default ASP server directory of `inetpub\wwwroot`). After the suggestion, I tried adding the pool user to the web app's custom location, but that didn't seem to work. Next, I moved the web app to the `inetpub\wwwroot` location and added the pool user to the folder, restarted the site via IIS and everything is now back to normal.

For future reference to anyone, easiest fix to a similar problem is to make sure your web app is in the default IIS server directory, and that your site pool's username is added to the application folder's [security permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780121(v=ws.10).aspx). I've not tried the fix for a custom location because it's not so important for me, but I'm guessing it will most likely also involve adding the necessary IIS default pool users (e.g. IIS_IUSRS) and the site pool's user.